# convert raw mySQL statement to laravel 4 eloquent with pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination, eloquent

I'm trying to express MySQL statment in Eloquent with pagination

code:

```
$query = "(SELECT city_name FROM Cities WHERE city_name LIKE '%" . 
   $keyword . "%') 
   UNION
   (SELECT area_name FROM Areas WHERE area_name LIKE '%" . 
   $keyword . "%') 
   UNION
   (SELECT sub_location_name FROM Sub_locations WHERE sub_location_name LIKE '%" . 
   $keyword . "%' )";
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: It appears to be the case for a [has many through](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
$cities = DB::table('Cities')->select('city_name')->where('city_name', $keyword);

$area=DB::table('Areas')->select('area_name')->where('area_name', $keyword);

$result=DB::table('Sub_locations')
        ->select('sub_location_name')
        ->where('sub_location_name', $keyword)
        ->union($cities)
        ->union($area)
        ->paginate(15);
```